# Adding content to tinyMCE in wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

My plugin create a buch of shortcodes, im wanting to have a little button above the MCE editor to add in these shorcodes ( aka gravity forms) the buttons are along the top where the "upload/insert" buttons are for adding media ( or a gravity form ). Then i need to have a modal window ( i think wp uses jquery ui, im familiar with this ) to select options for the shortcode then insert the html/code via js im guessing into the editor... only i looked myself and could not figure it out. Im pretty ok with php and js so no need to dumb it down.

i think this would be a good question for the community !

thanks guys.

Comment: ok im hot on the trail i will keep people posted. so far i found the action "media_buttons"

Comment: ok another hook has turned up and its looking better "media_buttons_context"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok guys so i worked it out.

you need to hook into an action called "'media_buttons_context'" it takes an argument called $context.

```
function add_shortcode_button( $context ) {

    $image_btn = METAMAKER_URL . "/images/form-button.png";
    $out = '<a href="#TB_inline?width=450&inlineId=select_form" class="thickbox" title="Add MetaMaker field"><img src="'.$image_btn.'" alt="Add MetaMaker field" /></a>';
    return $context . $out;
}
add_action('media_buttons_context', array( $this, 'add_shortcode_button'));
```

you would then need to  add in some html and js for the modal window pop up

Answer (score 3):

Theres a really good chance this is going to break (if it hasn't already) when you upgrade to WP 3.5.  The media_buttons_context has been deprecated so you now need to be using media_buttons.  Below should work in 3.5.

```
<?php
add_action('media_buttons', 'add_shortcode_button', 11));

function add_shortcode_button() {
    $image_btn = METAMAKER_URL . "/images/form-button.png";
    echo '<a href="#TB_inline?width=450&inlineId=select_form" class="thickbox" title="Add MetaMaker field"><img src="'.$image_btn.'" alt="Add MetaMaker field" /></a>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Two minor things to note going from media_buttons_context to media_buttons which further helped me to convert my code.  1. The media_button action does have a parameter anymore.  2. It should echo (instead of return) its (html) code.

Answer (score 0):

Hey man [here is the best tutorial ever about adding button to wp editor](http://brettterpstra.com/adding-a-tinymce-button/). It shows all aspects of it.

Comment: That tutorial is for adding buttons to the MCE editor bar not the small line of media upload buttons above that ousite the actual editor. but thanks dude